# How do I remove duplicate values from an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have multiple values for each key in the hash. Here, I print the values of each key

```
print "$var:",join ',',@{$hash{$var}},"\n";
```

Output of the above print statement is:

```
ABC:1,2,3,1,4,2,
DEF:9,3,4,5,3,5,
```

Now, I want to remove duplicates in the values. The desired output is,

```
ABC:1,2,3,4
DEF:9,3,4,5
```

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I like how [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)'s uniq handles this. The subroutine is quite simple, and can be used as-is, or through the module.

```
my %seen;
my @dedupe = grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @{$hash{$var}};
```

The subroutine from the module looks like this:

```
sub uniq (@) {
    my %seen = ();
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```

This code preserves the initial order of the list.

Comment: Hmm, do you use defined types of variables in function header all time?

Comment: If you mean do I personally use prototypes, then the answer is no. That sub is copy pasted from the module. I considered removing it, because as a general rule prototypes should not be recommended to beginners, but since it was basically a quote, I left it as it was.

Comment: yeah, i heard about it. but i don't understand, why people use it in CPAN modules.

Comment: Well, they do have a purpose. On the other hand, many people use them for no good reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Using [**`List::MoreUtils::uniq`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils#uniq):

```
@$_ = uniq @$_ foreach values %hash;
```

Answer (score 2):

That it's in a hash is irrelevant.  What you're wanting to do is dedupe the values in an array.

Look at the `uniq()` function in List::MoreUtils module http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/

You can also do it yourself like so:

```
my %h = map {($_,1)} @array_with_dupes;
my @deduped_array = keys %h;
```

This is all covered extensively in [the Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array?) under "Data: Arrays".

Comment: The do-it-yourself solution does not preserve the initial order of the elements.

Comment: That wasn't specified as a requirement.  I can see how you'd infer it, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to remove duplicate values from an array you can use this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @array = ('a','b','c','c','e');
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;
my @out = keys %hash;
printf("%s",join(',',@out));
```

Comment: This method does not preserve the initial order of your list.